# Add N tags to a LOT of objects using acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulk, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using the acts_as_taggable_on gem on a Rails (Ruby 1.9.3) project.
I provide a form to my admins to add 1..n tag(s) to list of resources (let's say clients).

I didin't find a way to do this in bulk. 
Right now I'm looping on every client and add one tag then save the object.
This is hurting the server a lot when I'm trying on X thousand clients, eventually creating a timeout.

I was wondering if there is a way to apply a tag to an ActiveRecord collection or something. If this is documented I'm deeply sorry, but I can't find somebody doing it anywhere.

I can see how to hack it by doing a custom SQL query all by myself, but I prefer to avoid hacking the gem like this, ofc.

Right now I'm doing something like this

Something like this

```
# Client.selection returns a clients collection
Client.selection.each do |client|
  tags_to_add.each{|a| client.tag_list << a}
  tags_to_remove.each{|a| client.tag_list.remove(a)}
  client.save
end
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Extra: well, I need to be able to remove 1..n tag(s) to a collection too!

Comment: Is there any specific ordering you need to use?  Can you show what ruby code you are using now that needs to be optimized for bulk insert?

Comment: Does your database support mass inserts?  That is, would it take a command like: `INSERT INTO foo (field1, field2) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)`.  This type of insert adds all rows in one pass, but not all DBMS's support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Saverio answser, I finally extended ActiveRecord::Relation with **add_tags** and **remove_tags** methods.

Here is an example:

```
# Our ActiveRecord::Relation
clients = Client.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 2.months)
# Our tags
tags_to_add = ['here','a','bunch','of','tags']
tags_to_remove = ['useless','now']
# Adding and removing tags
# (You can specify the tagging context as a second parameter) 
clients.add_tags(tags_to_add).remove_tags(tags_to_add, 'jobs')
```

I created a [Github repo](https://github.com/xumi/ActsAsTaggableOnActiveRecordRelation) for the patch, hope this can help!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use directly the Tagging model. Something like the following could be used (suppose the taggable objects are of the same class)

```
Tagging.transaction do
  client_ids.each do |cid|
    tag_ids.each do |tid|
      values = ["Client".inspect, cid, tid].join(", ")
      Tagging.connection.execute "INSERT INTO taggings (taggable_type, taggable_id, tag_id) VALUES (#{values}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id"
    end
  end
end
```

The deletion is much simpler

```
Taggings.where(:taggable_type => "Client", :taggable_id => client_ids, :tag_id => tag_ids).delete_all
```